# MySQL group by get data from latest entry

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL table with AT&T wireless users ranging over a couple of months. I'm trying to see who has used the most data over those months, but some of the User Names on the Wireless Number accounts have changed, as well as their data plan. Here's the query I'm trying to run:

```
select Wireless_Number, User_Name, sum(Total_KB_Data_Usage / 1048576) as Total_GB_Usage, avg(Total_KB_Data_Usage / 1048576) as AVG_GB_Usage, Data_Pooling_Rate_Plan_Code
from att
group by Wireless_Number
order by Total_GB_Usage desc
limit 20;
```

Here's a preview of what I get back (some data omitted for privacy)

```
| Wireless_Number | User_Name        | Total_GB_Usage | AVG_GB_Usage | Data_Pooling_Rate_Plan_Code |
|-----------------|------------------|----------------|--------------|-----------------------------|
| XXXXXX3330      | XXXX CRADLEPOINT | 1452.6883      | 181.58603750 | B                           
| XXXXXX4638      | XXXX CLARK       | 392.4903       | 49.06128750  | B                           
| XXXXXX1819      | XXXX RAMSEY      | 346.8210       | 43.35262500  | B                           
| XXXXXX0847      | XXXX WYNIA       | 265.9175       | 33.23968750  | B
```

The problem is that 'Ramsey' is no longer the holder of that account, now it's 'Welch'

```
select monthname(Month) as Month, Wireless_Number, User_Name
from att
where Wireless_Number like 'XXXXXX1819';
```

:

```
| Month    | Wireless_Number | User_Name   |
|----------|-----------------|-------------|
| October  | XXXXXX1819      | XXXX RAMSEY |
| November | XXXXXX1819      | XXXX WELCH  |
| December | XXXXXX1819      | XXXX WELCH  |
| January  | XXXXXX1819      | XXXX WELCH  |
| February | XXXXXX1819      | XXXX WELCH  |
```

1819 is just one of the numbers that has changed so far. I want to select the last row in my initial query which used a group by, but I need to still query all of the months in order to get accurate sums and averages. How to I go about doing this?

Edit:
The Wireless_Number does not change, only the User_Name and Data_Pooling_Rate_Plan_Code may have.

```
| monthname(Month) | Wireless_Number | User_Name         | Data_Pooling_Rate_Plan_Code |
|------------------|-----------------|-------------------|-----------------------------|
| October          | XXXXXX3330      | XXXX CRADLEPOINT  | B                           
| November         | XXXXXX3330      | TEMP LTE INTERNET | BDP10GBO                    
| December         | XXXXXX3330      | TEMP LTE INTERNET | None
```

Here's on that changes Plans, which is persistent from March on.

```
| Month    | Wireless_Number | User_Name  |  Data_Pooling_Rate_Plan_Code                   
|----------|-----------------|------------|---------------------|
| January  | XXXXXX1819      | XXXX WELCH | BDPIPJ5GB           |
| February | XXXXXX1819      | XXXX WELCH | Multiple Rate Plans |
| March    | XXXXXX1819      | XXXX WELCH | MBSL5GWTO           |
```

I'm not going to disagree that that data is bad, but I feel like this is something I should be able to do.

Edit 2:
My primary key is the Wireless_Number.
Here's what I'd like to see from an ideal query:

```
| Wireless_Number | User_Name         | Total_GB_Usage | AVG_GB_Usage | Data_Pooling_Rate_Plan_Code |
|-----------------|-------------------|----------------|--------------|-----------------------------|
| XXXXXX3330      | TEMP LTE INTERNET | 1452.6883      | 181.5860375  | NONE
| XXXXXX4638      | XXXX CLARK        | 392.4903       | 49.0612875   | MBSL5GWTO                   |
| XXXXXX1819      | XXXX WELCH        | 346.821        | 43.352625    | MBSL5GWTO                   |
```

Comment: Surely, your data has actual account and line numbers that can be referenced outside of the telephone number?

Comment: Order in a table isn't guaranteed.  We need a way to order the data some date or ID which denotes passage of time or sequence.  Do you have a date field or some ID (which always increments up)?  (note month isn't good enough as you could have months over years)...

Comment: @Jacobm001 It does not, sadly.

Comment: @xQbert I do have a Month column formatted as a date.

Comment: Month alone isn't good enough to solve this; you need a full date or an ID that always increments.  is "month" a true date containing year?

Comment: @xQbert It is, formatted like '2004-10-01', which would be October. November would be '2004-11-01'.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the results I wanted, I just reversed my entire database. I did so by doing

```
create table reversed
select * 
from database
order by Month desc;
```

When I ran my queries against this database, I got the results I wanted. I realize this is probably bad practice, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to simply extend your `group by` clause to include the `User_Name`. If you have line `a` that is shared between two users, that will produce a record for each of them.

```
select 
  Wireless_Number
  , User_Name
  , Data_Pooling_Rate_Plan_Code
  , sum(Total_KB_Data_Usage / 1048576) as Total_GB_Usage
  , avg(Total_KB_Data_Usage / 1048576) as AVG_GB_Usage
from 
  att
group by 
  Wireless_Number
  , User_Name
  , Data_Pooling_Rate_Plan_Code
order by 
  Total_GB_Usage desc
limit 20;
```

You may want to introduce some additional logic to only select people who only currently have that number.

Comment: I have tried this, but not with any additional statements. The only problem I see with this is that the 'XXXX Cradlepoint' changed named to 'TEMP LTE' in November, so I'd still like the usage on that to be included under the same Wireless_Number. Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: @TheDetective: It's always helpful when you add in additional information after an answer is suggested.

Comment: @TheDetective: If both the phone number and account name can be changed randomly without an account number, there is literally no way to do what you want. The data is simply bad.

Comment: @Strawberry: What?

Comment: @Strawberry: Oh good point. I completely ignored that existed. I've added it to the group by what little the whole thing seems to matter.

Comment: @TheDetective: I still don't see any data that's guaranteed to be stable. What's the new column you added? That doesn't look unique to the user, so it doesn't change anything

Comment: @TheDetective: You could probably mitigate a decent amount of the issues with a clever ETL process, but it'll still have a certain percentage of error that just can't be resolved.

Comment: I fixed the column. Also, what is and ETL process?

Comment: @TheDetective: ETL stands for [extract transform load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load). It's the process by which data is pull from a system, manipulated, and then stored in a data warehouse. In this case, you'd want to extract from your database, and reinsert into a new table.

Comment: @TheDetective: I'm betting you could programatically go through the data and make an attempt at guessing grouped accounts, but it would be a lot of work and very error prone.

Comment: @TheDetective: At this point, I would give up and go to whoever/whatever sourced this information and tell them you need a constant identifier. No amount of SQL will solve the fundamental problem of missing data.